# Open an app by clicking on an URL in android

Tags: android

Check this out : [Open an app when clicking on a url iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12037712/open-an-app-when-clicking-on-a-url-ios)

I'd like to do the same in android. Is it possible?

Comment: did u want open another app from your app?

Comment: nope from an URL on a website or in an email

Comment: Yes, Its possible, Modified your Intent Action for launch Activity in manifest file.

Comment: open url link to based actions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking for a custom intent

The manual on intents can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) and an example of setting up a custom one can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448213/how-to-implement-my-very-own-uri-schema-on-android)

Answer (score 2):

Check out this two links:
Hope that will help in overcoming your problem.

Visit [Launch custom android application from android browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958701/launch-custom-android-application-from-android-browser)

Visit [Make a link in the Android browser start up my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469908/make-a-link-in-the-android-browser-start-up-my-app/3472228)